# bool(false) в массиве

Tags: php, mysql

Вечер добрый!

Подскажите, стоит подрядят 4 запроса

```
    $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_manufacturer WHERE name = '$p_brand'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result); 
    $proizv_id = $data['manufacturer_id']; 

    $qr_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oca_label WHERE name = '$p_shildik'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result2);
    $p_shildik_id = $data2['label_id'];  

    $qr_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_category_description WHERE name = '$p_categ'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data3 = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result3);
    $p_cat_id1 = $data3['category_id'];     

    $qr_result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_category_description WHERE name = '$p_cat_other'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data4 = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result4);
    $p_cat_id2 = $data4['category_id'];
```

Если сделать

```
 var_dump $data , $data2 , $data3
```

то выдает

> bool(false)

4 все нормально, выводит массив.
Подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: Во всех таблицах есть поле `name`?

Comment: Да, везде есть name

Comment: переменные для поиска `name` не содержат нехороших символов?

Comment: Обычные русские буквы, если скопировать запрос с уже готовыми значениями - то все находит

Comment: Просто 3 и 4 - одинаковые запросы, только отличие - что если одно слово - то работает, я сейчас заметил, если 2 слова через пробел, то не хочет в коде искать, но работает в phpmyadmin

Comment: тогда попробуйте  вывести на экран текст запроса с подставленными переменными

Comment: как вариант - `LIKE` вместо =

Comment: кстати, про русские бувы - возможно, что кодировка для них и для пробела разная. Попробуйте `mb_convert_encoding`  или подобное

Comment: $qr_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_category_description WHERE name = 'Зимняя обувь'") or die(mysql_error());
  $data3 = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result3);
  $p_cat_id1 = $data3['category_id'];   

var_dump ($data3);

ответ bool(false)

Comment: Кодировка выдает ASCII, UTF-8
как определить - в какую нужно перекодировать что бы воспринимало пробелы?

Comment: Экспериментируйте... У меня такое бывало, русские (ЮТФ по-вебу) и пробелы-запятые и т.п. кодировались по-разному. В сборной солянке СУБД не понимала вопрос. Тут надо проверить и кодировку БД, и соединения, и РНР, и много еще чего. Экспериментируйте, судя по коду - Вы только начинаете разбираться. Универсального ответа нет...

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать!

Comment: Как минимум 1) не используйте расширение mysql, оно не развивается уже более 10 лет и в PHP7 вообще удалено. Используйте либо mysqli, либо PDO. 2) Никогда не собирайте запрос таким образом. Используйте подготовленные запросы - это позволит вам избежать большого количества проблем, возможно даже ваша текущая разрешится сама собой. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php